# How to make featured image clickable? -Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How to make all the featured image clickable automatically? As it's Wordpress theme, I can only edit php or add css.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554683/make-featured-image-clickable-wordpress

Comment: i think at the time of adding feature image , it asked to choose from media and give a link box at the right side of the opened pop-up (through which you are going to choose image). where you can add link. and it will become clickable...

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes you are right but i think that functionality it depends on which theme are you use.

Comment: Reina try my following code it may helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this code to your theme’s functions.php file.

This code simply adds a link around the code generated to display featured images or post thumbnails on your website.

```
function wpb_autolink_featured_images( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {
    $html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title( $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';
    return $html;
    }
    add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpb_autolink_featured_images', 10, 3 );
```

This code will also add a link around featured images on single post pages. If you don’t want to link featured images on single post to the same post, then use this code.

```
function wpb_autolink_featured_images( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {

If (! is_singular()) { 

$html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title( $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';
return $html;

} else { 

return $html;

}

}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpb_autolink_featured_images', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the functionality of a featured image has no link attached to it. Different themes use the functionality of featured image differently. The new Twenty Nineteen theme, for example, uses it as the background for the page header, behind the post title.

So it will be better to make a child theme of your parent theme and edit the php file to set a link. Without editing the code you cannot set the link of the featured image.

Answer (score 0):

Insert image > Click on the desired cell you want to insert it > Down on the right: “Linked to” > Personalized URL.